# Android app to compare similar images side-by-side and delete blurrier one

Tags: android, images, photography, image-viewer, duplicate-files

I've been using XnView for this on Windows, it has a side-by-side comparison mode where zooming into one image zooms into the other at the same time, so you can take several pictures of the same scene, then compare details side-by-side and delete the inferior ones until only the best is left.

[image]

I sync all my phone's photos with my computer, compare them on the computer, and the deletions sync back to the phone.  It would be nice if there were an Android app that does this directly on the phone, though.  Know of any?

(Similar to [Side-by-side image viewer for Android with RAW (DNG) file support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/62316/8363) except that one didn't get answered, because it was based on a misunderstanding of raw images.)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [Photo Compare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.want.imagecompare). It's an app I wrote and have been maintaining exactly because I couldn't find any good image compare app for Android.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious how to use it.  I open it, it shows me folders, then I go in one and select a photo, and then it shows me that photo and the next one in the folder, then I can zoom and pan, which is good, and there's a box which is clickable as a checkmark, "Image was added to selection".  I can barely see the checked box on top of my image.  I'm not sure what to do after checking a box.  Is that box for the images I want to delete or the ones I want to keep?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @endolith. When comparing images, there's an action menu (top right) which should help you along. Maybe also check out this blog https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-compare-two-photos/ reviewing the app.

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand how to use it. You can compare two images at a time, and select one of them, but you can't do a "round-robin tournament" of a group of images? And then you can either delete the selected images or "Delete all others".  But what is "all others"?  There was never any initial selection of a group of images. Does it delete all others in the folder, for instance?  That would be disastrous in a Camera folder.

Comment: In other words, if I take 7 images of the same flower, and 5 images of the same mushroom, all stored in the same folder, and I want to keep only 1 best flower and 1 best mushroom, and delete the others, how do I do that with your app? The Pic Perfect app does the elimination process well, for example, but it could use some improvement in the interface

Comment: Thanks for the example use case; this is one where PhotoCompare can definitely be improved. With the current version, you'd actually have to select the *unwanted* ones and then delete those.

Comment: Ok, but I have to manually handle the comparisons?  If the best are D>A>B>E>C, for example, I have to compare A,B, select B for deletion, then A,C, select C, then A,D, select A, then D,E, select E, by scrolling through the top and bottom pane?  It's more confusing than Pic Perfect, which automatically shows you every pair you need to consider within a selected group.

Comment: I wish it went back to the same folder after I'm done deleting some images. Navigating back to the same place a bunch of times is annoying. Also it doesn't actually delete anything that I delete?  :/

Comment: @endolith the delete option is available after you "show selected images". And Simon thank you for making and publishing this app! It works so well, and better than the others I tried. Though if you update it, you might consider making the delete actions available sooner, not needing to go into the "show selected" screen.

Answer (score 1):

Found an app that does this:

[Pic Perfect (Image Compare)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sufficientlyadvancedapps.picperfect)

Pros:

- Shows two pictures at a time, cycling through all pairs to find the best
- Zooms both simultaneously
- Can delete or move the pictures

Cons:

- Interface is not clear

  - Has Quick vs Complete mode, or Sequence vs Multiple mode, which seem to be the same thing??
  - Gives you the option to delete the perfect pic, which I thought was to delete the non-perfect pics, because why would you want to delete the perfect one??
- Would be nice if I didn't have to navigate to the Camera folder every time.
- Would be nice if it remembered that I want to do nothing to the perfect picture and delete the others.
- Slow to open the folder navigation